# Approximation of $\chi_{[a,b]}$ by continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis

let $\chi_{[a,b]}$ be the characteristic function of the interval $[a,b]$. My question is :

1-Is it possible to find a sequence of continuous functions which *uniformly* converges to $\chi_{[a,b]}$ ? (probably not)

2- Let $0 \leq a < b \leq 1$,  is it possible to find a sequence of continuous functions $\phi_n$ such that $\int^1_0 \phi_nf \to \int^1_0 \chi_{[a,b]}f= \int^b_a f $ ? where $f$ is a Lebesgue integrable function (probably yes, but I do not know how to show it)

I already appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1:Any uniform limit of continuous functions is continuous. It's a fairly straightforward $\epsilon-\delta$ proof to show this. (If you just mean continuous on $[a,b]$, the trivial constant sequence will work, but you probably meant continuous on a larger set.)

For 2: take functions whose graphs "form" trapezoids that are closer and closer to the rectangle "formed" by the graph of $\chi_{[a,b]}$.

Comment: Thanks ! You mean the answer to question 1 is yes ?!

Comment: If you are on a set in which $\chi_{[a,b]}$ is continuous yes. If not a non-continuous function cannot be a uniform limit of continuous functions.